# Logical short-circuit vs. Physically short circuited

Tags: transmission-line

Can the logical short-circuit point on the transmission line with short-circuit terminal be physically short circuited?

(By "logical short-circuit" I mean the position where the voltage is zero and the current is maximum on the physically separated parallel double wires. That is to say "The logical short-circuit point refers to the voltage wave node in the standing wave")

Comment: 李伟勤 - Hi, FYI I have deleted your comment, as it just repeated what you have added into the the question. The same information is not needed in the question *and* as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

**Short-circuit at the end of a transmission-line**

When you short-circuit a transmission line at its end-point, the EM wave travelling down will be reflected back up the t-line to the source-feed-point. In other words, the wave propagating down the line (which of course is real power and this real power needs to find an outlet) will take the only route it can and, that route is back up the transmission-line to the source-feed-point. If the t-line is half a wavelength long then this sets up a nice standing wave.

**Short-circuit that is half a wavelength along a transmission-line**

If a "long" t-line is terminated in its characteristic impedance but there is a short-circuit at half a wavelength from the source-feed-point, then the power going down the line in the form of an EM wave now has the option of continuing down to the end of the t-line or reflecting back to the source. Both options look like 50 ohm paths so both are viable and so is power.

**AC response**

Output spectrum of a 1.5 m t-line when there is a "near" short 0.5 m from the feed-end: -

[image]

Notice that at 200 MHz, 400 MHz, 600 MHz etc. there is no attenuation to the signal passing to the load (a 50 Ω termination). Circuit used in micro-cap: -

[image]

Ignoring DC, 200 MHz is the lowest frequency at which there is no attenuation. This is because the electrical distance from feed-point to the short-circuit is 0.5 λ. In free-space, 0.5 metres would correspond to a 0.5 λ at 300 MHz but, for a cable, the velocity of propagation is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$.

This equals 200,000,000 metres per second and not the speed of light (300,000,000 metres per second). Hence, 200 MHz (and multiples) is/are which there is zero attenuation.

**Caveat**

If the source end has zero ohm driving impedance then, the 50% portion of the wave that was initially reflected from the "short" is now reflected at the source and, when this portion again reaches the "short", 50% of that wave continues to the end of the line. After a short time of to-ing and fro-ing, all the wave energy reaches the load but only at specific frequencies corresponding with the "short" being half a wavelength (or multiples) down from the source.

If the source impedance is 50 Ω then this will not happen the same way.

**Summary**

If in doubt, get hold of a freely available (and free) simulator and experiment. It'll save you a lot of time and you can explore these things yourself. I recommend micro-cap.

Comment: Earlier comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129555/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-logical-short-circuit-vs-physically-short-circ). Any further comments posted here should be relevant to this answer and also be an [allowed use of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) - anything else may be deleted.